# Eslint "semi" rule doesn't check the end of class methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I've added the `semi` rule to my config, like this:

```
'semi': ['error', "always"],
```

It doesn't seem to work on class methods.

```
export default class ExampleComponent extends PureComponent {
  state = {...};

  changeFilter = value => this.setState({ filterString: value }) //expect error here
```

It doesn't react to the fact that there is no semicolon at the end of method statement. Am I doing something wrong? Is it even supposed to check for that?

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/semi

Comment: The code here does not show any class methods, but [public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields#Public_fields), which are [not supported](https://eslint.org/demo#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiZXhwb3J0IGRlZmF1bHQgY2xhc3MgRXhhbXBsZUNvbXBvbmVudCBleHRlbmRzIFB1cmVDb21wb25lbnQge1xuICBzdGF0ZSA9IDA7XG5cbiAgY2hhbmdlRmlsdGVyID0gdmFsdWUgPT4gdGhpcy5zZXRTdGF0ZSh7IGZpbHRlclN0cmluZzogdmFsdWUgfSlcbn1cbiIsIm9wdGlvbnMiOnsicGFyc2VyT3B0aW9ucyI6eyJlY21hVmVyc2lvbiI6MTEsInNvdXJjZVR5cGUiOiJtb2R1bGUiLCJlY21hRmVhdHVyZXMiOnt9fSwicnVsZXMiOnt9LCJlbnYiOnt9fX0=) yet.

Answer (score 0):

It should check for class methods as well, check if your eslint is configured and working properly in the project. Do you get error if your don't put semi after state object?

Comment: No, deleting semicolon after state does nothing as well.
Interestingly enough, it also doesn't react to a lack of semicolon at the end of a normal function outside of class. But DOES react if it's an arrow function

```
function hello() {
  console.log(1);
} //no eslint error here

const hello2 = () => {
  console.log(1);
} // eslint error here
```

Comment: ESLint config seems to be alright, but I don't understand how that would break the rule. Every other rule in the config works fine.

Comment: which version of eslint are you using?

Comment: Can you try: `"semi": [2, "always"]`